# in Android, intent.setData(Uri) causes AlarmManager to not fire

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-broadcast, android-alarms

I am using this code to fire an intent:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(MY_ACTION);
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("content://myapp.name.provider/triggerassignablepairs/10");
intent.setData(myUri);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 10, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000, pendingIntent); //set it to 10 sec after current time
```

in this form, the alarm will not fire.

However, it will fire if I omit `intent.setData(my_obj.uri)` then it will fire.
Is this normal behaviour, is there a way to explain it?

Any suggestions on how to solve this? My interest in including the `uri` is both to retrieve the database entry from my `ContentResolver` (which I could use `intent.putExtras` for) but also to differentiate the particular alarm from others that will be referencing other database entries.

Comment: Why don't you pass the value into that and parse it in wherever you receive it?

Comment: @jcage: have you seen my answer ?

Comment: I have and I am marking it as accepted. is <data android:scheme="content"/> sufficient for this to work?

Comment: @jcage: please see edited answer, test it and let me know if it works or not. As you said, it should be sufficient with `scheme` attribute alone :)

Comment: @jcage: so, tried it ?

Comment: I am, but I cannot get it to work. Btw, does the <action> need to be missing from <intent-filter>? Also,  it appears that if <data android:scheme="content"/>  is present, not settting a uri on the intent, then the BroadcastReceiver does not intercept it either. Would that be right?

Comment: @jcage: can you post your manifest file where you have declared the receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a `Uri` to an `Intent` using the `setData()` method, you need to add the `<data>` tag in the `intent-filter` of your `BroadcastReceiver` in the app manifest, and specify a combination of `scheme`, `host`, `port`, and `path` attributes corresponding to the `Uri`.

In your case the alarm is indeed fired but the `BroadcastReceiver` does not intercept the `Intent`.

**Example:**

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.somedomain.MyReceiver">

    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="content" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

**References:**

**1.** [**`<data>`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

**2.** [**Intent `<data>` Test**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#DataTest).